# Prohibit passwords from being the same as the account ID or user ID [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a password policy need to apply at my ROR application.

Prohibit passwords from being the same as the account ID or user ID.

For example: System will prompt error if I use the wording contain of 'alex' if my username is 
alex@google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom validation, in your `User` model

```
validate :password_content

def password_content
  self.errors.add(:password, "cannot contain username") if password.include?(user_name[/[^@]+/])
end
```

It will throw a validation error if password contains user_name. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of include?

```
if password.inlcude? user_name[/[^@]+/]
  do something
end
```